# How do i run Nvidia Digits without import errors

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, digits, nvidia-digits

I just tried to install Nvidia Digits 6.1.1 on my Ubuntu 16.04 Pc. I did every steps carefully but at the end of the installation i get this error on startup.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/kenan/digits/digits/__main__.py", line 70, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/kenan/digits/digits/__main__.py", line 55, in main
    import digits.webapp
  File "digits/webapp.py", line 7, in <module>
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import socketio
  File "/home/kenan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "/home/kenan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/client.py", line 7, in <module>
    import engineio
  File "/home/kenan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/engineio/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .client import Client
  File "/home/kenan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/engineio/client.py", line 2, in <module>
    from json import JSONDecodeError
ImportError: cannot import name JSONDecodeError
```

i appreciate any suggestions. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. If anyone needs, here is the way i did,

first i deleted `from json import JSONDecodeError` line in file `client.py` which is located at `./local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/engineio/`

after that modification i got an error on lib `werkzeug`

and the solution is that;

```
pip install werkzeug==0.16.0
```

After these steps Digits worked.